# Field containing numbers and letters

Tags: mysql, sql

I just have started to learn SQL. I have found in Internet few interesting project for beginners. In one of them I should create the `TABLE` named `library` which is containing fields like `nameOfBook` etc. The most important is `ID` field which is `Primary Key`. This field must be 5 character length, but first two must be numbers and rest must be letters.

Is there any way to make it? 
I am using newest `mySql`.

Comment: Yes, there **is** a way to make it (just use a string). Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Why is 'Is it possible to...' a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Comment: Voting to close this question as "too broad." Stack Overflow is not your personal tutoring site. If you have just started to learn SQL, you should break out a book or a tutorial and learn it. There's even a simple tutorial included in the MySQL manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html